# windows phone 7.1/7.0 - Reading from IsolatedStorage in Application_Launching event

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

The best practices for Windows Phone 7 says not to include any time consuming code in the Application_Launching event handler.  This includes reading from IsolatedStorage. They mention to do it asynchronously.

The question I have is, after launching the application, I want to take the user to his preferred screen. There are different views in my app that user can choose to keep as their preferred setting. How can I implement this scenario without reading from IsolatedStorage? Where else can I store user settings to read quickly and navigate to that screen?

Any help with this is greatly appreciated because if I add code to access IsolatedStorage, it is taking longer for the app to load. Thanks.

Comment: You should be able to load a couple things from isolated storage without taking too long. For example, my app loads a List<> of a class I have with 5 properties, with about 10 items, and it still loads within 2 seconds.  Another thing you could do since your supporting Mango, is allow the user to pin their desired app-entry-point via a SecondaryTile. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431744%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend looking at using IsolatedStorageSettings to hold this but having an animated loading page displayed while you query this and which then triggers navigation to the actual page the users wants when known.
The page(s) you navigate to should then [remove the loading page from the backstack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationservice.removebackentry.aspx).